# FFI for PHP - Installing this module in MAMP 7.4.12

Tags: php, mamp, ffi

I'm trying to install the FFI module for PHP. Having a hard time locating it and actually installing it on my mac book which is running MAMP Pro 7.4.12

also, an alternative would be upgrade MAMP to PHP 7.4.23, it has 7.4.12 and 8... I think if I can upgrade to 7.4.23. then FFI will work on it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!